# Android studio. Gradle sync error. Project "projectame" refresh fail

Tags: android

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEXNX.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDtgH.png)

I have tried multiple solutions including:-
1. Invalidate cache and restart
2. re-installing gradle
3. deleteing .gradle folders
4. uninstalling,re-installing android studio

Also, my project was working very well much yesterday. The sdk's that i downloaded also seem to be missing now(I made sure not to delete the sdk folder after uninstalling). The only thing i did was system recovery on my dell-pc ( do not delete files mode)

Comment: On each of the keyword in the gradle scripts, it says cannot resolve symbol 'include','buildscript',etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using git or any other vcs? If yes, you could clone working project and eliminate project files are corrupted.
At screen I can see that you haven't recent version of AS - try to download latest version from [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: Nope not using git or any other vcs. Can't download latest version atm.

Comment: Did. On each of the keyword in the gradle scripts, it says cannot resolve symbol 'include','buildscript',etc